# Django/Android User Profile page

Tags: android, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django-Rest-Framework to build a mobile web app. I'm trying to create a profile page for a given user once they log in. This is my first time building a mobile web app and ReST so I'm a little confused as to how profile pages are handled.

I know with web apps Django's template service can load all the users content from different models at once.

My question is how is this properly handled in a ReSTful way for Android?

i.e. do I send the serialized user model along with all their content in different models in one JSON response , or when the page activity starts it makes requests for each model content it needs to load the page, i.e. /getposts, /getcomments ...?

Comment: What you do highly depends on your needs. Many times, there are multiple API calls to load a single page.

Comment: Ok thank you. I was wondering if multiple API calls was too much or inefficient since non-ReST app load in one request.

Comment: @dylan7 Not at all.. in rest api you only fetch relevant data, where in case of webapp you need all static files, html, etc.. If possible, you should try to get all profile data from one endpoint though (by embedding related data in the same json content).